# Sequence diverging to infinity is not bounded above?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

> **Problem:**
>   Prove that $(a_n)$ -> $\infty$ implies that $(a_n)$ is not bounded above.

**My attempt:**

Let $C>0$ be arbitrary. Let $(a_n)\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

By definition, $\forall C>0$, there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$\forall n>N_1: a_n>C.$$
That indicates that there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$n+2>n+1>n>N_1.$$
This implies that $$\ldots \geq a_n+2\geq a_n+1\geq a_n>C.$$

So by the definition of an increasing sequence, $(a_n)$ is increasing as it tends to infinity. This indicates that there doesn't exist $u\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: u\geq a_n$$
because for every $u\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists a $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n>N_2: a_n>u$.

Let $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$. Then $\forall n>N: a_n>u$.

**My questions:**

1. Could you please tell me if my proof is right and how and where I could improve it?
2. Is there a better / more elegant way to prove this?

It would be nice if any arguments were as rigorous as possible.

Comment: $\forall$ C $>$ 0, there exists a N $\in$ the naturals such that $\forall$ n $>$ N, $(a_n)$ $>$ C @Piwi

Comment: (it may be a silly question) so can we assume that $a_n > a_k\,\,\forall n>k$

Answer (score 2):

Let $(a_n) \to \infty$. **Assumption:** $(a_n)$ is bounded above.

Therefore, there exists $u \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n\leq u.$$

But in the beginning we let $(a_n) \to \infty$ which according to your definition means that for all $C>0$, especially for $C:=u>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\forall n> N:a_n>u.$$
As the two statements above contradict each other, our assumption must be wrong and so $(a_n)$ is not bounded above.

Comment: Seems a tad bit vague, can you or anyone please write a solid proof?

Comment: @Robbie Which part is it you don't understand or feels vague to you?

Comment: @Piwi, This is what I wrote
Let C $>$ 0 be arbitrary
Let $(a_n)$ -> $\infty$ as n -> $\infty$
By definition, $\forall$ C $>$ 0, there exists $N_1$ $\in$ the Naturals such that n $>$ $N_1$, $a_n$ $>$ C
That indicates that there exists $N_1$  $\in$ the Naturals such that $n+2 > n+1 > n > N_1$
This imples that ... $\geq$ $a_n+2$ $\geq$ $a_n+1$ $\geq$ $a_n$ $>$ C.
So by definition of a increasing sequence, $(a_n)$ is increasing as it tends to infinity.
This indicates that there doesn't exist u $\in$ $\Re$ s.t. $\forall$ n $\in$ the Naturals, u $\geq$ $a_n$ because...

Comment: $\forall$ u $\in$ $\Re$ there exists a $N_2$ $\in$ the Naturals s.t. $\forall$ n $>$ $N_2$, $a_n$ $>$ u
Let $N$ = $max(N_1, N_2)$
Then $\forall$ n $>$ $N$, $a_n$ $>$ u